# Get an executable EXE with cmake and Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, qt-creator

So I've been using Qt Creator with cmake and compiling to an EXE

But how do I get to execute it outside of Qt creator?

If I just start it from the directory where it is placed it doesn't run because the DLLs it needs are missing.

How do I get those? Those DLLs aren't my own as my project doesn't contain any DLLs

Ideally I'd have the directory with the EXE and all the DLLs it needs

Comment: "But how do I get to execute it outside of Qt?" - Qt is just a library/framework, so the phrase "execute outside of Qt" has a little sense. You probably mean "execute outside of **Qt Creator**". You could add the path to Qt dll's to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Maybe you want Visual Studio to create a win32 program which runs without any DLL dependencies, other than standard system files. I don't know if Qt has the same option or not. Make sure to set "Runtime library" to "multi-threaded" ("not DLL")

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't want to get rid of the DLLs, just have them, like in the same directory

Comment: @Tsyvarev but that only works as long as I don't want to execute it on a system that doesn't have Qt installed

Comment: You probably get an error when starting on its own. Search for the error message online.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the error message is that it can't find a function provided by one of the DLLs

Comment: Please [edit] your question and quote (!) the full error message! That will allow others that search for that error message to find solutions here. Also, maybe, someone else already asked a similar question where you can get an explanation of the situation and possible remedies.